# Install WebChimera Prebuilt on Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, electron

I am writing an electron based application and want to use webchimera. However when I want to install (with npm) the wcjs-prebuilt package I always get the following error:

**No WebChimera release found matching your environment**

I use Ubuntu 16.04.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MoviePlayer",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "builder": "^3.2.1",
    "electron": "^1.4.3",
    "electron-ipc-plus": "^1.3.3",
    "hound": "^1.0.4",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "movie-art": "^1.0.6",
    "parse-torrent-name": "^0.5.4",
    "recursive-search": "^1.0.1",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1",
    "nedb": "^1.8.0",
    "wcjs-player": "git://github.com/jaruba/wcjs-player.git",
    "wcjs-prebuilt": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "wcjs-prebuilt": {
      "runtime": "electron",
      "runtimeVersion": "v1.4.3",
      "version": "v0.2.7"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wcjs-prebuilt` only supports mac and windows. From the docs:

> Target platform (**supported: `win` / `osx`**. Default value: machine's platform)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/wcjs-prebuilt#configuration (emphasis mine)

---

Possibly related: https://github.com/RSATom/WebChimera.js/issues/69.